# powerpoint watermark not showing in slideshow

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013, slideshow

In my presentation I use slide masters that have a watermark in the corner.  This watermark shows when I create or edit my slides.  However, when I launch the slideshow the watermarks are not present.  How do I make them appear?

Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot or sample file would help.

Comment: I spoke to the person that provided the template. He said the templates are designed to do this.  They are meant for use with a product called Camtesia that captures your screen for inclusions on videos. As a part of this the watermark cannot show in the slideshow since it is replaced with a better for video watermark.  However they show the water mark when you are creating slides so you do not put content in the same place as the watermark.